Antigravitation by sufficient torsion
If the gravitational field is coupled to fermionic matter according to the Einstein-Cartan theory, non-zero torsion is generated. It seems however, that only if the fermonic matter is extremely densely packed, that sensible amount of torsion is created in space-time that it can have notable physical effect.
Such a scenario can above all take place right before a big crush or right after the big bang of the universe.
Poplawski apparently predicted that the torsion would actually prevent the big crush to happen, instead it would lead to an immediate rebounce of the universe. So whereas curvature leads to apparent attraction of bodies, torsion would actually do the opposite, i.e. have an anti-gravitational effect.
Why would the geometrical effect of torsion on space-time make that to occur, in other words what is the mechanism?

Very nice question

What is torsion in this case? In differential geometry, torsion is an additional geometric structure that one can define on a manifold : the non vanishing of $[\nabla_a,\nabla_b]f$ for any scalar field $f$ will indicate non-zero torsion. But this has nothing to do with fermions or matter-field in general

@KP99 the Einstein-Cartan theory predicts an algebraic relationship between spin tensor and torsion tensor. In case of very dense fermonic matter, the  spin tensor and consequently the torsion tensor's components would be large.

ahh right, my bad.  I missed the Einstein-Cartan theory mentioned in your post above
